# How to install and run the Tor service in windows ? (windows v.10)

Tags: windows, installation, service, tor

I have python script that sends requests at onion site and takes response. It was working fine in ubuntu , tor service was used for that , but since I switched to windows it's not working, **how do I install tor service and run it in Windows 10 ?**

Answer (score 2):

Got to [torproject's page](https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/), download the **Windows Expert Bundle**.
When you open the **.zip** file, you will find a **Tor** folder.
Extract the folder to your system (*may c drive*).
Open **CMD.exe** (as Admin), navigate to the folder and than type

`c:\Tor\tor.exe –-service install`

Then your service is installed. :)

You can access the tor on `127.0.0.1:9050`

If you want to setup your Browsers:
Open `Internetoptions` > `Connections` > `LAN-SETTINGS` (may via IE/Edge)
Hit the `Checkbox` on Proxyserver.
Click on `Advanced` add `IP 127.0.0.1` and `PORT 9050` to `Socks`.
In the Bottom you can choose on what Domainendings the Tor should **NOT** listen too.

Hit `Ok` and you're done.

If you want command line tools to use the proxy, you could route your request over your tor service by passing `URL`, `IP` and `PORT` to [`CURL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) connection.

**CAUTION**

When using win 11, this my not work properly.

[@Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350221/dave) came up with a solution in the comments and [an extra answere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73738182/1906168) for all those who experiencing some problems in install or starting the service

Comment: The answer does install the service but when I ran the service I got

    Running on a Post-Win2K OS, so we'll assume that the LocalService account exists.
    IMPORTANT NOTE:
        The Tor service will run under the account "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService".  This means
        that Tor will look for its configuration file under that
        account's Application Data directory, which is probably not
        the same as yours.
    Done with CreateService.
    Service installed successfully
    StartService() failed : Access is denied.

I also couldn't start with `sc start Tor` either.

Comment: @Dave is this a question, a note or.... in the end you say you could not get it running under win2k. This answere is for win10, idk if this is the same under other os. Also my answere is based on my experience and contains all the info i needed to get it working for me. I also had to add a config file and im sure there where more places where he is looking for config files but i'm not sure right now since this is 1 year ago :D

Comment: I was using Windows 11 on a new machine. For some reason the tor install script didn't work for running the service. I didn't have permissions, even as an Administrator. The answer below, from Start9 does work for me for installing and running the services.

Comment: @Dave ok, thank you for mentioning this. The OP asked for win10. But i will add some to my answere and point this to you.

Answer (score 0):

Partially following the [instructions from Start9](https://start9.com/latest/user-manual/connecting/connecting-tor/tor-os/tor-windows).

Download the [expert bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/) and extract it. Use the signature to verify the file integrity. Alternatively, install the Tor Browser because the Tor browser should automatically update when launched.

Start Command Prompt as Administrator mode by right clicking on the Command Prompt application and select Run as administrator in the start menu.

Create a `tor` service by using the the following command as an example: `sc create tor start=auto binPath="<PATH TO>\Tor\tor.exe -nt-service"`

Then start the service with `sc start tor`.